# LDAP API Error: Server is unwilling to perform

Tags: php, ldap

I can get list of usernames, unlock users, verify username/password, get days to expire for a password, but I cannot change the frigging password. Why not?

```
public function changePassword(string $username, string $current_password, string $password): bool
  {
    $result = false;

    $connection = ldap_connect('ldaps://' . self::HOST . ':' . self::PORT);
    if ($connection) {
      ldap_set_option($connection, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
      ldap_set_option($connection, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
      ldap_set_option(null, LDAP_OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 7);
      if (@ldap_bind($connection, "uid=$username,ou=people,dc=bsg.na.baesystems,dc=com", $current_password)) {
        //$userpassword = '{MD5}' . hash('md5', $password);
        $userpassword = '{sha256}' . base64_encode(hash('sha256', $password, true));
        //$userpassword = '{sha384}' . base64_encode(hash('sha384', $password, true));
        $result = @ldap_mod_replace($connection, "uid=$username,ou=people,dc=bsg.na.baesystems.com,dc=com", [
          'userpassword' => $userpassword
        ]);
      }
    }

    if (!$result)
      log_message('error', __METHOD__ . "\n" . ldap_error($connection));

    return $result;
  }
```

Comment: What LDAP server are you talking to? Active Directory? OpenLDAP?

Comment: It's a Linux LDAP server. I presume OpenLDAP.

Comment: Have you asked the server admins about this, then? Could it be that the server is configured to require the "change password" exop instead of an attribute modify? Could it be that you're trying to use an unsupported hash algorithm? _(Do the server admins know that you're trying to use algorithms that are unsuitable for password storage?)_